# using weinre and device (target) is not showing up

Tags: android, cordova, weinre

I installed weinre using node on my system then ran weinre on the cli to start up the server. then i added:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

to my head section of my sample phonegap app and changed origin to * to allow all connections.

But I still do not see my device showing up on the weinre page - client/#anonymous under targets.

What gives and is there some other setup i'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your script tag to

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/target/target-script-min.js"></script>
```